# reports toolbar shows the next page and a question mark in the toolbar "Page Of"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, reporting, report

I have this report that I am trying to fix, it shows "1 Of 2?" (with that question mark) while it should show "1 Of 5". Here is an image

[image: Report toolbar showing question mark]

How can i fix this? if anyone can please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue, you need to set the property of the pagecount to actual and not estimate (I think its the default) which is why it was showing like that. You can change it when binding the report.

```
this.objReportViewer.PageCountMode = PageCountMode.Actual;
```

Comment: <RS:ReportViewerHost ID="ReportViewerControl" ShowPrintButton="false" PageCountMode="Actual" runat="server" />